# Lendo array e salvando com php

Tags: php

Estou tentado salvar o resultado deste Json em Php porém quando entro no foreach da respostas os dados ficam incorretos no banco.

```
{"questionario":[{"id_base":"661","id_usuario":"1","id_pesquisa":"29","id_varejo":"265285","respostas":[{"Pergunta":"OS","Resposta":["Windows","Linux","Macintosh OSX"]},{"Pergunta":"Plese select from the list","Resposta":["PHP","C#","Ruby","Shell","Objective-C"]}],"data_inicio":"2018-05-08 09:53:08"}]}





public function saveResult($post) {
    $array = $post;
    foreach ($array['questionario'] as $value) {
                $iduser      = $value['id_usuario'];
                $idPesquisa  = $value['id_pesquisa'];
                $idVarejo    = $value['id_varejo'];
                $idBase      = $value['id_base'];
                $data_inicio = $value['data_inicio'];
                $respostas   = $value['respostas'];
                foreach($respostas as $val){
                    $pergunta = $val['Pergunta'];
                    $resposta = $val['Resposta'];
                    if(is_array($resposta)){
                        foreach($resposta as $resp){
                           $resp;
                        }    
                    }else{
                        $resp = $val['Resposta'];
                    }

            try{
            $db = Database::conexao();
            $qry = "INSERT INTO `resultado`(`id_pesquisa`,`id_varejo`,`id_usuario`,`id_base`,`pergunta`,`resposta`,`data_inicio`)VALUES(
              :idPesquisa,
              :idVarejo,
              :iduser,
              :idbase,
              :pergunta,
              :resposta,
              :data_inicio)";

            $statement = $db->prepare($qry);
            $statement->bindValue(':idPesquisa', $idPesquisa);
            $statement->bindValue(':idVarejo', $idVarejo);
            $statement->bindValue(':iduser', $iduser);
            $statement->bindValue(':idbase', $idBase);
            $statement->bindValue(':pergunta', $pergunta);
            $statement->bindValue(':resposta', $resp);
            $statement->bindValue(':data_inicio', $data_inicio);
            $statement->execute();    

         } catch (PDOException $e){
                 echo $e->getMessage();
                 $db->rollBack(); 
         }        
         }//2 foreach    
    }//1 foreach          
 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. Qual erro exatamente ocorre?

Comment: Adicionei uma foto de como esta alocando no banco, ocorre que se eu tenho mais de uma resposta para uma pergunta o meu codigo esta salvando assim e nao todas as respostas para todas as perguntas.

Comment: cara, pra que serve esse if verificando array com foreach dentro?

Comment: estava validando se a resposta era um array mas agora que vi que ela sempre sera um array mesmo que contenha somente uma resposta nela

Comment: pois é, o erro deve estai ai, vc esta querendo salvar o array no banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformei o array de Respostas em um `json` para você salvar no banco de dados:

```
public function saveResult($post) {
    $array = $post;
    foreach ($array['questionario'] as $value) {
                $iduser      = $value['id_usuario'];
                $idPesquisa  = $value['id_pesquisa'];
                $idVarejo    = $value['id_varejo'];
                $idBase      = $value['id_base'];
                $data_inicio = $value['data_inicio'];
                $respostas   = $value['respostas'];
                foreach($respostas as $val){
                    $pergunta = $val['Pergunta'];
                    $resposta = addslashes(json_encode($val['Resposta']));
                }
            try{
                    $db = Database::conexao();
                    $qry = "INSERT INTO `resultado`(`id_pesquisa`,`id_varejo`,`id_usuario`,`id_base`,`pergunta`,`resposta`,`data_inicio`)VALUES(
                      :idPesquisa,
                      :idVarejo,
                      :iduser,
                      :idbase,
                      :pergunta,
                      :resposta,
                      :data_inicio)";

                    $statement = $db->prepare($qry);
                    $statement->bindValue(':idPesquisa', $idPesquisa);
                    $statement->bindValue(':idVarejo', $idVarejo);
                    $statement->bindValue(':iduser', $iduser);
                    $statement->bindValue(':idbase', $idBase);
                    $statement->bindValue(':pergunta', $pergunta);
                    $statement->bindValue(':resposta', $resp);
                    $statement->bindValue(':data_inicio', $data_inicio);
                    $statement->execute();

                } catch (PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    $db->rollBack(); 
                }
         }//2 foreach    
    }//1 foreach          
}
```

Caso não queira o `json` no banco de dados, faça assim:

```
$resposta = inplode(",",$val['Resposta']);
```

Comment: wess ficou otimo! So uma duvida, neste trecho "$resposta = addslashes(json_encode($val['Resposta']));" ele esta salvando assim no banco "[\"Macintosh OSX\",\"Linux\"]" , como posso fazer ser salvo desta forma? "Macintosh OSX,Linux" separado por virgula?

Comment: é porque é um json, né, quando vc precisar dele e puxar do banco, no campo respostas vc usa `json_decode` e vai virar um array novamente

Comment: @CarlosLopes duro é a gnt vir dar a resposta e ter gnt q vem sinalizar negativamente, vai entender

Comment: é que ele não precisa ser puxado do banco como um json, Neste caso quando eu realizo o select nesta tabela eu recrio o resultado em um json, por isso precisava salvar em uma linha separada por virgula.

Comment: já me ajudou muito!!! Realmente Muito obrigado Amigo vou pesquisar um pouco mais aki!!! Obrigadão!!!

Comment: editei a resposta